# jQuery: KeyUp Event for all Fields with Custom Parameter

Tags: jquery

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8xo98vzk/9/

I have multiple TextAreas, and I need to define a common On-Max event for them with a custom MaxLength param. My strategy is to have a Map that pairs ID->MaxLength. But something isn't working. Is this the right approach?

HTML

```
<input type="textarea" id="textarea1" /><br/>
<input type="textarea" id="textarea2" /><br/>
<input type="textarea" id="textarea3" /><br/>
<input type="textarea" id="textarea4" /><br/>
```

jQuery

```
var maxlengthmap = {};
maxlengthmap['textarea1'] = 5;
maxlengthmap['textarea2'] = 3;
maxlengthmap['textarea3'] = 7;
maxlengthmap['textarea2'] = 1;


$('input[type=textarea]').each(function () {
    $(this).keyUp(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > maxlengthmap[$(this).id]) {
        alert('Exceeded');
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: its `$(this).val()` not `$(this).value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is in this line:

```
if ($(this).value.length > maxlengthmap[$(this).id]) {
```

Change it to:

```
if ($(this).value().length > maxlengthmap[$(this).id]) {
```

or, in plain js:

```
if (this.value.length > maxlengthmap[this.id]) {
```

Moreover, you don't need the **.each** you can simply write:

```
$('input[type=textarea]').on('keyup', function (e) {
```

From your comment:

> When I added an Alert, it's still not showing the alert at the limit, I'm allowed to type more...

If you need to stop at max numer of chars you need to change the event from **keyup** to **keypress**. Because this last event let you stop (or prevent default action) typing other chars.

The snippet:

```js
var maxlengthmap = {};
maxlengthmap['textarea1'] = 5;
maxlengthmap['textarea2'] = 3;
maxlengthmap['textarea3'] = 7;
maxlengthmap['textarea2'] = 1;


$('input[type=textarea]').on('keypress', function (e) {
    var currentValue = this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if (currentValue.length  > maxlengthmap[this.id]) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Exceeded');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="textarea" id="textarea1"/><br/>
<input type="textarea" id="textarea2"/><br/>
<input type="textarea" id="textarea3"/><br/>
<input type="textarea" id="textarea4"/><br/>
```

Comment: thanks but the **Change to line in your post is identical to the first line, did you mean "this" without the $(this)

Comment: @geneb. Updated Thanks

Comment: When I added an Alert, it's still not showing the alert at the limit, I'm allowed to type more: https://jsfiddle.net/8xo98vzk/14/

Comment: I think you mean `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your code.
Please note : this is jquery.keyup, all in lowercase.
In your html, the input type is *text*, not *textarea*

Correct code :

```
var maxlengthmap = {};
maxlengthmap['textarea1'] = 5;
maxlengthmap['textarea2'] = 3;
maxlengthmap['textarea3'] = 7;
maxlengthmap['textarea4'] = 1;


$('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
    $(this).keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > maxlengthmap[$(this).attr("id")]) {
        alert('Exceeded');
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: any input with an invalid type is treated as a text input. so even though the textarea input type is technically incorrect, it won't break anything

Comment: It won't break anything, that is right; but it isn't a valide html syntax

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/8xo98vzk/10/

```js
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > parseInt($(this).data('max-char'))) {
    alert('Exceeded');
    $(this).focusout();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textarea1" data-max-char='5' /><br/>
<input type="text" id="textarea2" data-max-char='3' /><br/>
<input type="text" id="textarea3" data-max-char='7' /><br/>
<input type="text" id="textarea4" data-max-char='1' /><br/>
```

Used data attribute `data-max-char` instead of an array for maximum characters in `input textbox`.

Rather than loop through all the input textbox, check only on the focused `input textbox`.

**Mistake in code**

- `$(this).value;` should be changed to `$(this).val();`
- `<input type="textarea">` should be changed to `<input type="text">`
- `keyUp` should be changed to `keyup`

Hope this will you.